# In Business Objects is there a way to change the color of each bar in a bar chart?

Tags: business-objects

I would like each bar in a business objects report to have a different color. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In Design mode, right-click on one of the bars, then select *Format Data Series* from the popup-menu.  Change *Automatic* to *Custom*, and you can then select the color to use.

I believe this functionality was first introduced in BI4.0

Comment: Thanks Joe....we are on BI4.2....but when I right click I do not see Format Data Series....something must be turned off.

Comment: Think i found the issue....we moved from BI3.x...to BI4.2. None of my converted report charts have the ability to format data series. When i create a new chart...it only shows up in black and white.

Comment: You might be in Reading mode, and/or using the HTML panel.  Make sure you are using the Java report panel, and that you are in Design mode.  (the Reading/Design modes are completely new in BI4).